# how to show that $Y= \{f\in L^{2}[0,1] \mid f(x)\geq x \text{ a.e.}\}$ is weakly closed in $L^{2}$

Tags: functional-analysis

> **Problem**: Let $Y= \{f\in L^{2}[0,1] \mid f(x)\geq x \text{ a.e.}\}$.  Show that
>   $Y$ is weakly closed in $L^{2}$.

My thought about solving this problem is that consider a sequence $\{f_{n}\}$ which converges to some $f$ weakly and to show that $f$ is also in the set $Y$. According to the definition of weakly convergence, $f_n \stackrel w\longrightarrow f$ if and only if for any $T\in (L^2)^*, T(f_{n})\longrightarrow T(f)$, and by Riesz Representation Theorem, we can express $T$ in terms of some $g$ in $L^2$. But I have no idea about how to proceed. I am new in functional analysis and I will be grateful to any inspiring replies. Thanks!

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself. Lastly, some would consider your post rude because it is a command ("Show..."), not a request for help, so please consider rewriting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f_0(x):=x$, and $S=\{f\in L_2[0,1]:f\geq 0\quad\text{ a.e.}\}$.

For each $g\in L_2[0,1]$ consider functional
$$
\phi_g:L_2[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}:f\mapsto\langle f,g\rangle
$$
One can show that 
$$
f\geq f_0 \quad\text{ a.e.}\Longleftrightarrow \int_0^1 f(x)g(x)dx\geq \int_0^1 f_0(x)g(x)dx\quad\text{ for all }\quad g\geq 0\quad\text{ a.e.}
$$
Hence 
$$
f\in Y\Longleftrightarrow \phi_g(f)\geq \phi_g(f_0)\quad\text{ for all }\quad g\in S
$$
This means that
$$
Y=\bigcap\limits_{g\in S}(\phi_g)^{-1}\left([\phi_g(f_0),+\infty)\right)
$$
Note that $(\phi_g)^{-1}\left([\phi_g(f_0),+\infty)\right)$ is weakly closed as preimage of closed set $[\phi_g(f_0),+\infty)$ under action of continuous linear functional $\phi_g$. Thus $Y$ is weakly closed as intersection weakly closed sets.

Comment: so clever! thx!

Answer (score 0):

The set $Y$ is convex and closed, hence weakly closed.

Comment: okay~but I have a question, why "convex and closed" leads to "weakly closed"? Can you give me a hint of how to prove it? That will be of much help! Thank you in advance!

Comment: This follows by the geometric version of Hahn-Banach (the second bullet in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn–Banach_theorem#Hahn.E2.80.93Banach_separation_theorem). Take a sequence $\{x_k\} \subset Y$ with weak limit $x$. Then, set $A = \{x\}$ and $B = Y$ in the above version of Hahn-Banach.

Comment: okay!Thanks a lot!!